# how to get in out when looping in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have code like this:

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    text =  cars[i];
alert( text);
}
```

My question how to put the `alert( text);`in out code for??

```
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        text =  cars[i];
  }
alert( text);
```

And get result like this:

```
BMW
Volvo
Saab
Ford
Fiat
Audi
```

Thank You

Comment: If you want a single alert that lists all cars then `alert(cars)` would do it, or `alert(cars.join(", "))` to add spaces. (No need for a loop.)

Comment: Try rewording your question please.

Comment: Please add the desired output to your question.

Comment: sorry my englis is bad,thanks,now my problem its solve

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the text variable each time inside the for loop.
You need

`text = text + ", " +cars[i];`

instead of

`text = cars[i];`